# Extracting values from API GET string

Tags: python, string, rest, api, get

I am making an API GET for a range of values across a date range.

How can I work through the returned string of values and pluck out specific values (in this case "day" and "value")

```
import requests

url = "https://api.something.com/rest/o/GHEYE/n/3/d/4/daily_client_count"

querystring = {
    "start":"2018-11-12T02:04:05",
    "end":"2018-12-13T02:04:05",
    "type":"",
    }

payload = ""
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'Authorization': "Bearer xxxxxx44bec4572xxxxxxxx",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "462xxxx-2ae4-4938-bae3-7a31xxxxx"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

This returns the following string...

```
{"resp_code":"SUCCESS","caller_ref":"654656465456564","server_ref":"65464655496545561","data":[{"day":"2018-11-12","value":1125,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":1125},{"day":"2018-11-13","value":2292,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":2292},{"day":"2018-11-14","value":1772,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":1772},{"day":"2018-11-15","value":2068,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":2068},{"day":"2018-11-16","value":2309,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":2309},{"day":"2018-11-17","value":2479,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":2479},{"day":"2018-11-18","value":2341,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":2341},{"day":"2018-11-19","value":1550,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":1550},{"day":"2018-11-20","value":1417,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":1417},{"day":"2018-11-21","value":1734,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":1734},{"day":"2018-11-22","value":1954,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":1954},{"day":"2018-11-23","value":343,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":343},{"day":"2018-11-24","value":16,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":16},{"day":"2018-11-25","value":36,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":36},{"day":"2018-11-26","value":29,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":29},{"day":"2018-11-27","value":34,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":34},{"day":"2018-11-28","value":30,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":30},{"day":"2018-11-29","value":25,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":25},{"day":"2018-11-30","value":852,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":852},{"day":"2018-12-01","value":572,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":572},{"day":"2018-12-02","value":639,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":639},{"day":"2018-12-03","value":848,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":848},{"day":"2018-12-04","value":678,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":678},{"day":"2018-12-05","value":884,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":884},{"day":"2018-12-06","value":288,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":288},{"day":"2018-12-07","value":542,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":542},{"day":"2018-12-08","value":185,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":185},{"day":"2018-12-09"},{"day":"2018-12-10","value":353,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":353},{"day":"2018-12-11","value":82,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":82},{"day":"2018-12-12","value":18,"wifi_client_connected":0,"usages":18},{"day":"2018-12-13"}]}
[Finished in 1.264s]
```

I'd like to loop through the string pulling out the VALUE for each DAY and printing them line by line for now.

Thanks.

D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for item in response.json().get('data', []):
    print('Day: {}, value: {}'.format(
        item.get('day', ''),
        item.get('value','')
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This prints the "value", but I would also like "day" to be printed alongside the "value" too.

Comment: I am trying this...

`print(item.get('value') + ' ' + item.get('day'))`

But I get a string/int mismatch error?

Comment: It seems that some items doesn't have value and `None` is returned. I placed default empty string. See edited answer.

Comment: This seems to work well...

`print item.get('day') ,  '-' , item.get('value')`

Gives...

`2018-11-12 - 1125
2018-11-13 - 2292
2018-11-14 - 1772
2018-11-15 - 2068
2018-11-16 - 2309
2018-11-17 - 2479
2018-11-18 - 2341 etc...`